# Mse traning больше чем Mse testing. PyTorch ANN

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, pytorch

```
inputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_train).float()
inputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(inputs_test).float()
outputs_train_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_train).float()
outputs_test_torch = torch.from_numpy(outputs_test).float()
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(4, 15),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(15, 15),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(15, 1)
    )
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')
criterion1 = torch.nn.L1Loss(reduction='mean')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.008)
for epoch in range(100):
    output = model(inputs_train_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (81403, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE train: ', loss.item())
    output = model(inputs_test_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_test_torch, (21654, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE test: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
for epoch in range(100):
    output = model(inputs_train_torch)
    loss = criterion1(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (81403, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MAE train: ', loss.item())
    output = model(inputs_test_torch)
    loss = criterion1(output, torch.reshape(outputs_test_torch, (21654, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MAE test: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

Out[]: 
Epoch:  86 MSE test:  0.03307786211371422
Epoch:  87 MSE train:  0.03682834655046463
Epoch:  87 MSE test:  0.031561754643917084
Epoch:  88 MSE train:  0.036547500640153885
Epoch:  88 MSE test:  0.028746912255883217
Epoch:  89 MSE train:  0.03666434809565544
Epoch:  89 MSE test:  0.02723623998463154
Epoch:  90 MSE train:  0.03619876876473427
Epoch:  90 MSE test:  0.02561429888010025
Epoch:  91 MSE train:  0.03621290624141693
Epoch:  91 MSE test:  0.025094548240303993
Epoch:  92 MSE train:  0.03558947145938873
Epoch:  92 MSE test:  0.024901267141103745
Epoch:  93 MSE train:  0.03537008538842201
Epoch:  93 MSE test:  0.024834109470248222
Epoch:  94 MSE train:  0.034832216799259186
Epoch:  94 MSE test:  0.0251359511166811
Epoch:  95 MSE train:  0.03468063473701477
Epoch:  95 MSE test:  0.024926314130425453
Epoch:  96 MSE train:  0.03419237211346626
Epoch:  96 MSE test:  0.025308404117822647
Epoch:  97 MSE train:  0.034069210290908813
Epoch:  97 MSE test:  0.02491961047053337
Epoch:  98 MSE train:  0.033683035522699356
Epoch:  98 MSE test:  0.025090258568525314
Epoch:  99 MSE train:  0.03355500474572182
Epoch:  99 MSE test:  0.02469632588326931
```

Почему MSE train больше чем MSE test. Как можно решить эту проблему? Пробовал поменять Lr и число элементов в слоях но лучший результат это.

Comment: тестовые данные сильно отличаются от тренировки? Если да, то это даже хорошо, что тест меньше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    output = model(inputs_train_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (81403, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE train: ', loss.item())
    output = model(inputs_test_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_test_torch, (21654, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE test: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward() # <-- обучение на лоссе теста!
    optimizer.step()
```

Так вы в итоге учите нейросеть именно на лоссе теста, поэтому она его хорошо и предсказывает! Учить модель нужно на трейне, а на тесте нужно только проверять качество обучения. А у вас всё наоборот получается, поэтому и качество на тесте больше, чем на трейне. Перенесите обучение на лосс трейна:

```
    output = model(inputs_train_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_train_torch, (81403, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE train: ', loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward() # <- теперь модель учится на трейне
    optimizer.step()
    output = model(inputs_test_torch)
    loss = criterion(output, torch.reshape(outputs_test_torch, (21654, 1)))
    print('Epoch: ', epoch, 'MSE test: ', loss.item())
```

Я, кстати, не уверен, что тут вообще нужен `optimizer.zero_grad()`, это не обнуляет обучение на каждой итерации цикла, у вас обучение вообще идёт со сменой эпохи?

Comment: Да идет сейчас добавлю кажись заработало

Comment: 'loss.backward(), optimizer.step()' И на тренин и на тестинг добавил и результат выше в вопросе добавлена

Comment: @AbishkozhaAmangeldin Ну, и туда и сюда добавлять не правильно. Тест (или валидационная выборка) нужен для того, чтобы проверять качество обучения (именно проверять уже обученную сеть, а не учиться на этих данных!) на независимой выборке данных, а если вы учитесь и на том и на другом, то лучше уж не делить данные на трейн и тест, а учиться на объединённых данных сразу, тогда качество обучения будет выше.

Comment: А все теперь понятно спасибо

Comment: Все работает как надо.